# MVCContrib grid - sorting a custom column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

Just started learning to use the grid so please excuse me for the possibly trivial question.

How can I sort by a column that uses another table property?
For ex. 
`column.For(cust => cust.LinkedTable.someProperty).Sortable(true);` 
definition results in a "Could not find a property called 'someProperty' on type MyProject.Models.Node" error (obvious - the property is actually MyProject.Models.Node.LinkedTable.someProperty)

One of my ideas was to create a helper:

```
column.For(cust => Helpers.ViewHelper.GetSomeProperty(cust)).Sortable(true);
```

This doesn't produce the error, but a column isn't getting sorted anyways.

In another words, is there any way to pass a string value to a column and make it sortable?

Should probably rewrite my sort function (just a OrderBy(...) now), but I don't really know how to start:) Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to recommend you the [JQuery grid](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

Check it out, it's very useful

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
column.For(cust => cust.LinkedTable.someProperty).SortColumnName(somePropertyID)
```

where `somePropertyID` is a attribute of table `cust`.